# Get reference to Compass sprite map when using @import

Tags: compass-sass, css-sprites

If I use the following to generate a sprite map:

```
@import "ui-icons/*.png";
```

How can I get a reference to the sprite map that has been created. I want to pass it to the [`sprite-position($map)`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-position) function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you import via `@import "icons/*.png"`, the variable `$icons-sprites` now contains the reference to the `sprite-map` function used by Compass' `@import` function.

The key is using `$<folder>-sprites` to reference that sprite map.